# Use .then and send res use Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm a beginner in `node.js` , I'm try to use .then and get the response from another file in `nodejs`

Admin.js

```
const convert = require("../Services/Convert");

convert.video(myfile, videoid).then((data) => {
            const mymessage = data.data.message;
            if (!mymessage.msgError) {
              console.log("GOOD")
            }
          });
```

Convert.js

```
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs"),
  cloudconvert = new (require("cloudconvert"))(
    "MjeYEgD8sZF7XIjvYftBirpmMJlsktjOSlL3RAogTr4VVXjRfWOS6dwTpa0Y19V9"
  );

module.exports = {
  video: (myfile, videoid) => {
    const ucuk = myfile;
    return fs
      .createReadStream(ucuk.path)
      .pipe(
        cloudconvert.convert({
          inputformat: "mp4",
          outputformat: "mp3",
          input: "upload",
        })
      )
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./upload/" + videoid + ".mp3"))
      .on("finish", function () {
        res.status(400).json({
          message: { msgError: true },
        });
      });
  },
};
```

This is the result

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: convert.video(...).then is not a function
```

Can someone explain to me why that is error and how to fix it ? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear how errors are being handled or why event "finish" is an error, but you would need to return a `Promise` to be able to use `then()` on `video()`. Something like:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const fs = require("fs"),
  cloudconvert = new (require("cloudconvert"))(
    "MjeYEgD8sZF7XIjvYftBirpmMJlsktjOSlL3RAogTr4VVXjRfWOS6dwTpa0Y19V9"
  );

module.exports = {
  video: (myfile, videoid) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const ucuk = myfile;
      return fs
        .createReadStream(ucuk.path)
        .pipe(
          cloudconvert.convert({
            inputformat: "mp4",
            outputformat: "mp3",
            input: "upload",
          })
        )
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("./upload/" + videoid + ".mp3"))
        .on("error", function(err) {
          reject(err); // use with `catch`
          return res.status(400).json({
            message: { msgError: true },
          });
        })
        .on("finish", function () {
          // finish is success?
          // if not, put resolve into whatever event is success
          resolve(); // to be able to use `then`
          return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'OK',
          });
        });
    });
  },
};
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: why I got this error bro ? 
            res.status(400).json({
                ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: Okay, yeah, it's because `res` is not anywhere in any of your files. You'd need to make `res` available in some way. Maybe add your route handler code to your question, as in where you specify the path, method, and middleware.

Comment: What are you using to handle request and response? Express?

Comment: hey bro , can you help me ?

Comment: To further assist, you need to provide how you are setting up your express routes. Please update your question with code for your routes.